# Why can't the gray bubble image be shown?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-chat, uibubbletableview

I am doing a chat iOS app with Swift. In `ChatLogController`, I added two bubble images to the chat screen.The blue bubble image is shown, but the gray bubble can't be shown. I am sure that I have added two images to the xcassets file.

```
static let grayBubbleImage = UIImage(named:"bubble_gray")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(22,26,22,26)).imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
static let blueBubbleImage = UIImage(named:"bubble_blue")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(22,26,22,26)).imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

let bubbleImageView:UIImageView =
{
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = ChatLogMessageCell.grayBubbleImage
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1)
    return imageView
}()
 if message.isSender!.boolValue
    {
        cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRectMake(48 + 8, 0, estimatedFrame.width + 16, estimatedFrame.height + 20)
        cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRectMake(48 - 10, -4, estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8 + 16, estimatedFrame.height + 20 + 6)
        cell.profileImageView.hidden = false
       // cell.textBubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
        cell.bubbleImageView.image = ChatLogMessageCell.grayBubbleImage
        cell.bubbleImageView.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
        cell.messageTextView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

}

else
    {
        cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 16 - 16,0, estimatedFrame.width + 16, estimatedFrame.height+20)
        cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 16 - 16 - 8, 0, estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8, estimatedFrame.height+20)
        cell.profileImageView.hidden = true
       // cell.textBubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 137/255, blue: 249/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.bubbleImageView.image = ChatLogMessageCell.blueBubbleImage
        cell.bubbleImageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 137/255, blue: 249/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.messageTextView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
```

Thanks.

[image: simulator image]

Comment: because background colour is same as grey bubble colour? put both of them with blurBubbleImage and see that you actually has the image view on it.

Comment: Big thank, i forgot to block the textbubble view color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using image rendering mode is `always template` so if your image is `png` and then you set imageview's tint color then it change the color of that png image. So, I think you are giving gray tint color to that image view so that image becoming gray and if your background color of that imageview is gray then you can't differentiate between them.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Big thank. I forgot to turn the gray background color off.

Comment: i need one help with above

Comment: @DilipTiwari : yes!

Comment: how can i create this bubble image with text inside i donot want to use lib

Comment: could i know ur skype id

Comment: for that you should ask separate question! Because it is very long question. and you have to some research for the same. No one will write full code for you! And sorry I can't share my skype id because of some restriction and policies !